# Expanding $f(x) = x^3\sin(4x)$ as a power series, then finding $f^{24}(0)$.

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the expansion of the function $f(x) = x^3\sin(4x)$ into a power series centered at point $0$, then find the derivative of $f^{24}(0)$.

> We use the formula: sin(x) = $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty
>  }\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{\left(2n+1\right)!}\cdot x^{2n+1}$
>
> f(x) =  $x^3sin(4x)$ = $x^3$ * $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty
>  }\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{\left(2n+1\right)!}$ * $(4x)^{2n+1}$ =
> $x^3$* $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^n\cdot
>  4^{2n+1}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}$*$x^{2n+1}$ = $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty
>  }\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^n\cdot
>  4^{2n+1}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}$*$x^{2n+4}$ 
> Not all the elements are
> visible so ... 
>  $x^3sin(4x)$ =   $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty
>  }\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^n\cdot
>  4^{2n+1}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}$*$x^{2n+4}$ = $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty
>  }\:a\left(n\right)\:\cdot \:x^n$ 
>  We equate k = 2n + 4  so
> n=$\frac{k-4}{2}$ 
>  And that's the part that I don't really
> understand. I have to show for which "n" what is happening but I don't
> know how to show it, so I'll just write it that way :  
>  where
> ∀$\ge$0  a(n) := {$\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\frac{n-4}{2}}\cdot
>  4^{n-3}}{\left(n-3\right)!}$ 
>  $f^{24}$(0) = 24! * $a(24)$ =
> $\frac{24!\cdot \left(-1\right)^{10}\cdot 4^{21}}{\left(24-3\right)!}$
> = $\frac{24!\cdot 4^{21}}{\left(21\right)!}$ = 3! * $4^{21}$

I would like to ask if this is the correct solution? I had such a "scheme" of solving during the lesson. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't you  confuse $f^{24}$ and $f^{(24)}$?

Comment: Oh I`am sorry. Yes, yes $f^{(24)}$. @user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to recognize that for some $n$, $a(n)=0$, like
$$
a(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{2}
  0, & n\leqslant 3 \text{ or } n \text{ odd } \\
  \frac{(-1)^{(n-4)/2}4^{n-3}}{(n-3)!}, & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much :)